# How to align the fo:table to the right or to the center inside of the fo:table-cell in XSL-FO?

Tags: xsl-fo

I forget the layout model of XSL Formatting Objects.
I used it actively but I don't remember it now.

The following code is wrong

```
<fo:block background-color="gray" text-align="right">
    <fo:table background-color="yellow">
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell><fo:block>99999999999</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</fo:block>
```

How can I align my table to center or put it to right?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm.. I forget to wrap my `fo:table` inside of the `<fo:table-and-caption>`.
This code is a working example

```
<fo:block background-color="green" text-align="right">
    <fo:table-and-caption>
        <fo:table background-color="yellow">
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>99999999999</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:table-and-caption>
</fo:block>
```

Comment: You could have put the `background-color` and `text-align` properties on the `fo:table-and-caption` and omitted the `fo:block`.

Comment: @TonyGraham There was a reason not to to do so for the sake of one of my formatters. Possibly it was an old Antenna House. Remember nothing now.